# JQuery $.fn not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a wrapper plugin for a richtext editor. Everything works on Chrome, but I need it to work for Internet Explorer 11. When the page loads, an error pops up (`Object doesn't support property or method 'editor'`). The JQuery documentation says IE should support (`$.fn`), so I'm confused as to what the problem is. Do I need to polyfill something?

editor.js

```
import { ImageDrop } from "./image-drop.js";

$.fn.editor = function (options) {
  const REQUIRED = typeof(options.required) != "undefined"
    ? options.required
    : true;

// the rest of the plugin goes here
});
```

index.html

```
<div id="editor"></div>

<script type="module" src="./image-drop.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./editor.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#editor").editor({
      required: true;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?  And are there any console errors?

Comment: I'm using jquery 3.3.1. There's no errors in Chrome, in IE there's an error that says Object doesn't support property or method 'editor'

Comment: Check your network console and verify that the `editor.js` file is being successfully imported.

Comment: Could also potentially be an issue since your using `type="module"`, if the two are not using the same instance of `jQuery`

Comment: Yes, the module was the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post the documentation link here. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation, just by trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what the problem was by trial and error. IE11 doesn't support modules, so `<script type="module">` cannot be run.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.